# Keras - Predict on model after learning sentiment data throws errors

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

My problem is in getting results through predict method in keras using tensorflow backend. But first a small introduction.

I am using

- Python 2.7.12
- Keras==1.2.1
- numpy==1.12.0
- tensorflow==0.12.1

I created a convolutional neural network like in these documentation: https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html

I trained the network with 11842 prepared twitter texts. The only individual change is that I have 3 possibilities for a result (0,1,2). I defined that in following code line:

```
preds = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
```

So the method fit works without a problem and I am achieving between 88-92% acc.

```
model_fit = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), nb_epoch=10, batch_size=128)
```

After the learning process I saved the model in .h5 format (also works fine).

Now I try to load the models and predict with them. First example (trained_model) is done via the same data I used to train ... because I wanted to compare them. The second example (trained_model_2) is done via new twitter texts (I collected earlier).

```
trained_model = load_model("trained_model.h5")
prediction_result = trained_model.predict(data_train, batch_size=128)
print prediction_result.shape ### Prints: (11842, 3)

trained_model_2 = load_model("trained_model.h5")
prediction_result_2 = trained_model_2.predict(data_predict, batch_size=128)
```

For comparing the training dataset with the "live / new" data set:

`print data_train.shape   # (11842, 1000)`

`print data_predict.shape # (46962, 1000)`

Also both are from type `dtype=int32`

Following code line raises the first error:

```
prediction_result_2 = trained_model_2.predict(data_predict, batch_size=128)
```

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,999] = 13608 is not in [0, 13480)
>        [[Node: Gather_1 = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](embedding_1_W_1/read, _recv_input_1_1_0)]]

Following code line raises the second error:

```
trained_model_2 = load_model("trained_model.h5")
```

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[0,999] = 13608 is not in [0, 13480)
>        [[Node: Gather_1 = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](embedding_1_W_1/read, _recv_input_1_1_0)]]

**EDIT**
Source Code of the methods I created. Method "trainModule" is only used for training the network / save it. The method "predict_sentiment" is used for my predict tests. The first prediction_results works and returns a numpy array with following shape **(11842, 3)**
[Code - pastbin](http://pastebin.com/vZ8bVpfW)

The whole error output: [Error output - pastbin](http://pastebin.com/uxEweWUn)

If some additional information is needed, I will update the question...

Comment: what kind of transformation did you do to get x_train, x_val from data_train?

Comment: For learning the model? I did it like in the link above. I shuffle all texts and multiply them with "VALIDATION_SPLIT"(for me 0.19) after them i split them between training and validation data. Or do you mean how do I get them to a numpy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the trained model can't find the word in the embedding matrix. That means I used a different vocabulary for training and prediction. Because the of the fixed vocabulary I need the same vocabulary for train and new data.

In general I only had to fix the tokenizer from:

```
tokenizer_predict = Tokenizer(nb_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
tokenizer_predict.fit_on_texts(texts_predict)
sequence_predict = tokenizer_predict.texts_to_sequences(predict_data)
```

To:

```
tokenizer_predict = Tokenizer(nb_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
tokenizer_predict.fit_on_texts(texts_train)
sequence_predict = tokenizer_predict.texts_to_sequences(predict_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it tried to access a list of [0, 13480) with the index 13608 (which obviously will not work). Someone else had also a similar issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2734
It seems he tried to access a vocabulary [0, 10000) with the index of 10535.

Comment: With print (len(data_train)), print (type(data_train)) I get following output 11842, <type 'numpy.ndarray'> ... For the prediction which is working for the train dataset. I get the same output for the live twitter dataset ... only the length is higher 46962, <type 'numpy.ndarray'> ... So it should be a nparray